# How can i escape unicode in a URL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I download images from the Web, but when I have something written in French, it crash like this link:

/uploads/pictures/000/075/967/medium/**grillardière**.jpg.

The problem is the URL doesn't wok with punctuation

Comment: That isn't called punctuation. It's Unicode.

Comment: In french language we call that punctuation :)

Comment: In computers, we call it Unicode. [Here is an explanation en francais](http://unicode.org/standard/translations/french.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode the special characters. For example, é is %E9, so it would be:

```
/uploads/pictures/000/075/967/medium/grillardi%E9re.jpg.
```

In Objective-C, you can do it like this:

```
NSString *newUrl = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: How can i do that programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to encode the foreign language characters. You can do this with a convenient `NSString` method:

```
NSString *cleanURLString = 
   [URLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```